# Data Ingestion tool playing up

Tags: vba, outlook, servicenow, data-ingestion

I am currently trying to make an ingestion tool that takes an email sent into Outlook and with one click allows all the information to be uploaded to a ticket in ServiceNow.

The issue I am having is that when the ticket is created in service now it either logs the ticket under the name "IT service desk" instead of the customer's name.

The way I have figured out how to get it to log it under the customer name then also adds a line of text in the description saying "incident logged by #(username) which again I do not want.

I cannot remove one without the other, so if I remove the line of code that removes the "Incident logged by #(username) it then also stops autopopulating the customer name. If I leave the "Incident logged by #(username) it does automatically populate the correct name.

I have added "company email address" below instead of the actual address.

```
Const olMail As Integer = 43

Sub SNTicket()
    Dim servicenowaddress As String
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim senderAddress As String
    Dim addresstype As Integer
    
    ' ServiceNow email address for the ticket recipient
    servicenowaddress = "Company email address"
    
    ' Get the currently selected item in Outlook
    Set objItem = GetCurrentItem()
    
    ' Check if the item is a mail item
    If Not objItem Is Nothing And objItem.Class = olMail Then
        ' Create a new mail item for forwarding
        Set objMail = objItem.Forward
        
        ' Sender E-mail Address
        senderAddress = objItem.SenderEmailAddress
        
        ' Searches for @ in the email address to determine if it is an exchange user
        addresstype = InStr(senderAddress, "@")
        
        ' If the address is an Exchange DN, use the Senders Name
        If addresstype = 0 Then
            senderAddress = objItem.senderName
        End If
        
        ' Configure the forwarding mail item
        objMail.To = servicenowaddress
        objMail.Subject = "#NoSig " & objItem.Subject
        objMail.Body = vbNewLine & vbNewLine & objItem.Body
        
        ' Remove the comment from below to display the message before sending
        ' objMail.Display
        
        ' Automatically send the ticket
        objMail.Send
    Else
        MsgBox "This is not a valid mail item.", vbExclamation
    End If
    
    ' Clean up
    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    
    ' Determine the currently active window in Outlook
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        Case Else
            Set GetCurrentItem = Nothing
    End Select
    
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: "The way I have figured out how to get it to log it under the customer name" - what is that way?

Comment: Appears you need to investigate how the ServiceNow ticketing application processes email.

Comment: @TimWilliams this block of code.    ' Configure the forwarding mail item
        objMail.To = servicenowaddress
        objMail.Subject = "#NoSig " & objItem.Subject
        objMail.Body = vbNewLine & vbNewLine & objItem.Body

Comment: Where is the question? What exactly is wrong with your current implementation of forwarding emails?